# How to get the actual drop location(not the destination) of a Uber Ride via API, after the ride completes?

Tags: uber-api

I can see the my actual drop location on the receipts page on riders.uber.com, but do not see that data in requests/{request_id}/receipt/ end point of the API. Is there an alternative to get this data ?

I see that a GET on requests/{request_id}/ gives the actual location of the a ride, but does this point also gives the same data on ride completion/cancellation ? On sandbox-api, on completion of ride, I get location as null, on a GET  requests/{request_id}/ call

Answer (score 0):

The Uber API doesn't expose this information. It provides the destination of a trip in the [request details](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests-details), but it does not update the destination based on the actual drop-off location.

As pointed out in the comments, ONE partial alternative for this use case might be to use the request details array of waypoints. However, it is only available for shared rides like UberPOOL.

Comment: If you read carefully the description for 'waypoints' field in the documentation, it states that this field is available only for shared rides, like UberPOOL. Also, even for shared rides, the 'waypoints' only indicate the destination, and not the actual drop off location, which could be known only after the ride complete, hence expected API endpoint for this information should be ride receipt.

Comment: Correct! It could be a partial alternative for shared rides. I updated my response to point that out